# How to install SharePoint WebPart WSP file with DLLs outside WSP?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, solution-deployment, gac, safe-controls

We develop WSP solutions and embed the DLLs within the WSP and give to our customers along with power-shell script to deploy the solution on their farm.

Today, we have purchased a WebPart from an Software company but they have provided to us a WSP along with 3 DLLS. Now, what would be the installation procedure to deploy this wsp?

1)  How do I install it?;

2)  Do I manually run gacutil? or drag and drop DLLs into the assembly folder?;

3)  And do I hardcode safe controls under web.config?

Also, isnt it a bad practice to keep DLLs outside the WSP? Please guide best practice and steps to install this webpart so we can use it in the site UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally all the artifacts should be part of the WSP itself. You should be simply Adding the solution and then deploying it. No need to manually adding the dlls to GAC and adding safe control entries.
You should get in contact with the company from whom you purchased the web part. They can provide you better guidance. However, I remember the days when I started working on WSS and had not heard of the tools like WSPBuilder, Visual Studio extensions etc. And I used to perform it all manually as you mentioned in your steps.

Comment: We have been chasing them about this issue, sadly there is no response and we would like to do it manually, could you provide the steps or are the steps I mentioned the right method..

Comment: In that case the steps you mentioned are right.

Comment: OK, so Step1:Run gacutil.exe for the 3 dlls. Then, Step2:Add the 3 dlls name as safe control in the web.config. Can you reassure this is correct plz.

Comment: If all the webpart contains is few dlls and no user controls which reside in control templates like for visual webpart or anything similar, then above steps should work.

Comment: And by the way you should test in Dev environment first just in case anything goes wrong